# underscore.js _.extend and a list argument with dictionaries

Tags: javascript, dictionary, underscore.js

I wonder if there is any way to easily extend an associative array with a set (list) of dictionaries. I came out with the following solution. I wonder, is there any more readable way for doing this?

```
var output = {};
_.extend.apply(this, [output].concat(input_list_of_associative_arrays));
```

Comment: There's `w = _({}); w.extend.apply(w, input_list)` but that's not much better. If you can modify `input_list` then you could unshift `{}` onto the front of it and use `apply` without the extra fiddling around.

Answer (score 2):

The better way to do this:

```
var foo = [{foo:1}, {bar:2}, {baz:3}],
bar = _(arrayOfObjects).reduce(function(a, b){ return _.extend(a, b); });
console.log(bar);
// {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}
```

If you don't care about extra properties:

```
var foo = [{foo:1}, {bar:2}, {baz:3}],
bar = _(arrayOfObjects).reduce(_.extend);
console.log(bar);
// {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3, 0:{foo:1, bar:2, baz:3}, 1:{bar:2}, 2:{baz:3}}
```